# How to start Android accounts configuration for my custom accountType?

Tags: android, account

In my app I have configured a custom accountType which is defined in my authenticator.xml. Accounts created by my app are already visible in global settings.

Since android already provides a user interface for deleting and configuring such accounts, I would like to start it from my app, so I don't have to implement this functionality myself.

What is the code for creating the required intent to jump directly to account configuration for my custom accountType?

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.provider.Settings;
ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS));
```

Add an extra to that intent called Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES with a value that is your account's authority, you can limit the accounts shown to just yours.
The value has to be in a string array.

Comment: How do I find out what the authority of my account is? Is it the accountType?

Comment: Check the docs ;)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS[/link]
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#EXTRA_AUTHORITIES[/link]

Comment: This might also help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html

Comment: I still don't get it. I understand, that the authority of the account is my app. But what is the real value for this? Is it the package of my app, which I can get from the context?

Comment: Well I've never used it myself. But I guess the package name is the correct value. It should work similar to a content provider authority, but I'm not sure about it. You have to do some digging yourself. I'm kinda busy at the moment. This may help http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html and this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html
I'm sure you are not the only one trying to do this, so it should not be that hard to find.